# Repeating tables with different default values

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, default-value

So am I making an InfoPath form that pulls in data from an inventory list and I have a drop down that is populated with all available items in the inventory, and when an item is selected it shows the picture and other important information.

The form has to implement repeating tables so users can make multiple selections, I want the first column in the repeating table to automatically display the item users have selected in the above drop down.  However, when users add a new row to the table and select their second item it over writes the first rows data.

so I am wondering if it is possible to make it that when a new row is added to the table, its default value is changed to what users have selected with out changing the previous selections?

I have tried messing with rules, but I didn't see an option for it to run only when a particular field is empty. I am considering adding a button to "Add Item" however I want to make sure that's the best solution (end users hate extra clicks).

Comment: There are ways to do it, I've done it in the past for a multi leg travel form where the previous repeating row value defaults to the next row. I can't seem to find the references I used any longer. It did involve rules and I think a separate index field i believe.